# hdf5 append to dataset adding by reference

Tags: python, numpy, reference, dataset, h5py

i'm reading some images that i wish to append to a dataset in hdf5:

```
with h5py.File(output_file, 'w') as hf:
    i = 0
    for p,meta in get_images( file_pattern, star_pattern ):
        if i == 0:
            hf.create_dataset(dsname, data=p[np.newaxis,...], maxshape=(None,p.shape[0],p.shape[1]), chunks=True)
        else:
            hf[dsname].resize( (hf[dsname].shape[0]+1), axis=0 )
            hf[dsname][-hf[dsname].shape[0]:] = p.copy()
        print( ".", end='')
        i = i+1
```

Where `p` is an `i` by `j` numpy array (greyscale iage) and `get_images()` returns a python generator of the image and meta data in a tuple.

so the problem is that when i re-read the outputted file, i see that all of the images are actually all identical. I assume because `p` is a reference to the numpy array that gets reused in the loop. I would have assumed that `p.copy()` should prevent this.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer if you used `ds = hf.create_dataset...` and then `ds.resize...` and `ds[i] = p`.  `i` if updated correctly should be the index of the newly created last slot.

Comment: `-hf[dsname].shape[0]:`, so if there are 10 items in the array, [`-10:`] references all of them.  You are putting `p` into all slots, not just the last. `[-1]` is the last.